# How to add nohup jupyterhub in service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, nohup, jupyterhub

Have installed jupyterhub locally. for starting it I'm using this command
`conda activate jupyterhub_environment` and then
`nohup jupyterhub`

how to add this commands in service so that it can start automatically when system starts using systemd

Comment: You will need to add more information. Is your system using systemd as the service management? In that case you could create a systemd-unit file and activate it.

Comment: Yes i'm using systemd

Comment: I suggest you to get familiar with it, then. This is a good document worth reading https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd#tabl-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Introduction-Units-Types
You can also read the man page `man 5 systemd.service` for explanation of the file you need to create and some examples.

Comment: conda activate is not working in systemd